# First Item kills next item up to array length is equal 1 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
  let ar = arr.splice(i, 1);
  console.log(ar.flat())
}
```

I have an array. 1 kills 2, 3 kills 4 like and array is [1,3,5]. 5 kills 1, 3 kills 5, and so on. Final operation is 3. How to do in JavaScript?

Comment: I think that removing elements from the array is making it harder to figure out an algorithm. I think the first step here is to figure out the steps and write them down in pseudo-code, don't worry about the language now. Just, what operations will you do?

Comment: Maybe, if instead of removing elements, you can set a `null` value to them. Then keep an index to iterate over the array, just an idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used Array.filter and switcher(to filter an element or not): this.del that works alternately(1/0) after each element of the Array. 0 is false(to filter), 1 is true(not to filter). The context of switcher (this) is relative to the while loop and remains after every turn.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
while (arr.length > 1)
  arr = arr.filter(() => this.del ? --this.del : this.del = +1, { del: 1 })
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: (preface: I didn't downvote this answer but it came up the review queue) This may have been downvoted because you didn't include an explanation as to why this answer should be accepted by the asker. Without information and context (explanations, links to documentation etc) answers like this are sometimes not well received (even if the code content is good)